# Spark collect()/count() never finishes while show() runs fast

Tags: scala, apache-spark, gradle

I'm running Spark locally on my Mac and there is a weird issue. Basically, I can output any number of rows using show() method of the DataFrame, however, when I try to use count() or collect() even on pretty small amounts of data, the Spark is getting stuck on that stage. And never finishes its job. I'm using gradle for building and running.

When I run

```
./gradlew clean run
```

The program gets stuck at

```
> Building 83% > :run
```

What could cause this problem?
Here is the code.

```js
    val moviesRatingsDF = MongoSpark.load(sc).toDF().select("movieId", "userId","rating")

    val movieRatingsDF = moviesRatingsDF
      .groupBy("movieId")
      .pivot("userId")
      .max("rating")
      .na.fill(0)

    val ratingColumns = movieRatingsDF.columns.drop(1) // drop the name column

    val movieRatingsDS:Dataset[MovieRatingsVector] = movieRatingsDF
      .select( col("movieId").as("movie_id"), array(ratingColumns.map(x => col(x)): _*).as("ratings") )
      .as[MovieRatingsVector]

    val moviePairs = movieRatingsDS.withColumnRenamed("ratings", "ratings1")
      .withColumnRenamed("movie_id", "movie_id1")
      .crossJoin(movieRatingsDS.withColumnRenamed("ratings", "ratings2").withColumnRenamed("movie_id", "movie_id2"))
      .filter(col("movie_id1") < col("movie_id2"))

    val movieSimilarities = moviePairs.map(row => {
      val ratings1 = sc.parallelize(row.getAs[Seq[Double]]("ratings1"))
      val ratings2 = sc.parallelize(row.getAs[Seq[Double]]("ratings2"))
      val corr:Double = Statistics.corr(ratings1, ratings2)

      MovieSimilarity(row.getAs[Long]("movie_id1"), row.getAs[Long]("movie_id2"), corr)
    }).cache()


    val collectedData = movieSimilarities.collect()
    println(collectedData.length)

    log.warn("I'm done") //never gets here

    close
```

[image]

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think you should not create new RDDs from within the transformation on the `moviePairs` dataset? (I refer to the two `sc.parallelize(.)`)

Comment: I also feel it's a bit inefficient. But Statistics.corr method expects a pair of RDDs. Would be nice if I had a way to pass just 2 Vectors to it. But this is not the case. And anyhow, this task seem to land itself well (if I print something after - it won't take long).

Answer (score -2):

Spark does lazy evaluation and creates  rdd/df the when an action is called.

To answer you are question

1 .In the collect/Count you are calling two different actions, incase if you are 
 not persisting the data, which will cause the RDD/df to be re-evaluated, hence 
 forth more time than anticipated.

2. In the show only one action. and it shows only top 1000 rows( fingers crossed 
   ) hence it finishes